# Pan recognizer in Custom View

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer, pan

I've added UIImageView in viewController and attached pan gesture recognizer, implemented handler and it works properly.
The problem occurs when trying the same scenario in customView, handler is never called.
UIImage in custom view has user interaction and multiple Touch enabled, as well as the UIView in the main ViewController.
please, help.

CustomView is loaded from xib:

```
@implementation previewView

-(instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    DLog(@"Initializing NDGPreviewViewWithCoder - from XIB");
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        [self commonInit];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)commonInit {
    //load the interface file from .xib
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"previewView" owner:self options:nil];        

    [self addSubview:self.view];
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you share screen shot of your custom view,your loaded nib is not assigned to any variable ?

Comment: I've managed to create recognizer programatically, but still the second recognizer created in xib would be nice to have (for future tasks).